# Tin Can API based Android App using Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator-mobile, tin-can-api

can anyone share some links to learn how to develop android app using Titanium Appcelerator and Tin Can API from basics. I am basically a Flash actionscript developer and have knowledge about SCORM 2004/1.2 standards. I want to know how can I develop mobile applications for e-learning using Tin Can API for more reliable and failsafe tracking. Also please mention which Tin Can supporting LMS available on the web.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to get started with Tin Can is [tincanapi.com](http://tincanapi.com?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=main?pmc=em-1). In particular, take a look at the [libraries](http://tincanapi.com/libraries/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=libraries?pmc=em-1) and a list of Tin Can [Adopters](http://tincanapi.com/adopters/?type=product&category=lrss&utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=adopters_lrss?pmc=em-1).

Once you've had a look at and tried out all these resources, you may have some more specific questions.